# Finiteness of the functional $\int_0^1 \frac{\phi(x)}{\sqrt{x}}dx$ in $L^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, definite-integrals, lp-spaces

Consider the following functional for functions in $L^2([0,1])$ $$\phi\to\int_0^1 \frac{\phi(x)}{\sqrt{x}}dx$$
Is this always finite? My guess is no, but the obvious check of $x^a$ for $a>-\frac12$ is indeed finite.

Can anyone prove this or, more likely, provide a counter example?

Comment: it is finite for all $\phi$ if and only if $x\mapsto \frac1{\sqrt x}$ is in $L^2$. This gives conditions on $a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comment, from general theory one knows that the integral $\int_0^1 g(x) \phi(x) \, dx$ will be finite for all $\phi \in L^2[0,1]$ only when $g$ itself is in $L^2[0,1]$.  And of course your function $g(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ is *not* in $L^2[0,1]$, so just as you suspect, your functional cannot be finite for all $\phi$ in $L^2$.

The general theory does not, of course, immediately provide a specific example of such a $\phi$.  In particular, because $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ is not itself in $L^2[0,1]$, the function $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ is not itself an example of such a $\phi$.  And as you point out in your attempt, your functional *does* happen to be finite on those functions $x^a$ that *do* happen to lie in $L^2[0,1]$.  So one has to look elsewhere in $L^2[0,1]$ for a specific example that is easy to compute.

But consider e.g. $\phi: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $\phi(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x} \ln(x)}$ if $0 < x < 1/2$ and $\phi(x) = 0$ otherwise.

Using the "substitution" "$u = \ln(x)$" it is possible to see that $-\frac{1}{\ln(x)}$ is an antiderivative of $\frac{1}{x (\ln(x))^2}$ on $(0,1)$, and hence that $\int_0^1 \phi^2(x) \, dx = 1/\ln(2)$ is finite, so that $\phi$ is in $L^2[0,1]$.

The same substitution helps to see that $\ln|\ln(x)|$ is an antiderivative of $\frac{1}{x \ln(x)}$ on $(0,1)$, which can be used to show that
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \phi(x) \, dx = \int_0^{1/2} \frac{1}{x \ln(x)} \, dx = +\infty.
$$

Comment: Can you elaborate on how we know $\int_0^1g(x)ϕ(x)$ finite implies $g$ in $L^2$? I can only think of the Reisz representation theorem, but that requires the functional be continuous. Is there some theorem which says that all functionals defined for all of $L^2$ are continuous?

Comment: @Andrew Good question (there isn't!). The argument I had in mind would use the structure of the functional, not just everywhere-definedness, to show boundedness. Suppose e.g. $g \geq 0$ and that $\int g \phi$ is finite for all $\phi \in L^2[0,1]$. The finiteness hypothesis allows the use of the dominated convergence theorem to show that the functional $\phi \mapsto \int g \phi$ on $L^2$ is the pointwise limit of the (bounded!) linear functionals $\phi \mapsto \int \min(g,n) \phi$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Boundedness of the pointwise limit then follows from the uniform boundedness principle.

Answer (score 1):

Your guess is right. Since you are in the critical exponent case, you have to use logarithms. Take $\phi(x) = 1/(\sqrt x\ln x)$ on $(0,1/2)$ and $0$ outside. Then
$$
\int_0^{1/2} \frac{\mathrm d x}{x\,\ln x} = -\infty
$$
since this is the integral of the derivative of $\ln \ln x$, but $\phi\in L^2$ since
$$
\int_0^{1/2} \frac{\mathrm d x}{x\, \left|\ln x\right|^2} = \left[\frac{-1}{\ln x}\right]_0^{1/2} = \frac{1}{\ln 2}.
$$